# Using canvas to grab pixel data from page

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, quicktime

If I have a QT video on a page (where QT is a requirement that can't be changed) how can I grab the pixel data of the current frame that is being shown with canvas? I am aware that this is possible with `getImage(videoElement, .....)` but I am looking for a solution that uses QT.

If getting the pixel data is not possible then is it possible to take a screenshot of the page using canvas and trim it perhaps?

Or am I going about this the wrong way and don't need to use canvas at all?

Comment: JavaScript cannot take a screen shot. What are using Server Side (PHP, ASP.NET)? Is the video being streamed - if so, what is the streaming server?

Comment: I realize JS cannot do this but I thought maybe there was a way to grab pixels from the page using canvas seeing as it can do it for images and video elements already.... server-side I am using ASP.NET. I do realize that a possible solution is just calling to the server to grab the frame, but I'd really like to investigate all options first.

Comment: As an aside, QT is a requrement because it can track to ANY frame not just keyframes like flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with canvas. The function you are referring to has nothing to do with canvas, it has to do with the video element. The video element returns a picture that the canvas can use, and the QT object (or embed) does not.

Answer (score 1):

Can you rely on java being available on the client?  If so, you could use an offscreen java applet (using the quicktime for java libraries) to talk with javascript and your quicktime plugin to get at pixel data for a given frame.  This solution requires loading the movie into the quicktime plugin AND into the applet.  See http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/index.html for a simplified api.

This is not a graceful solution.  I don't like it.  Just brainstorming.

Comment: unfortunately cannot use java applets. can use flash however if thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to pre-process the quicktime movie, and keep pixel data on your server.  Ajax the correct frame's data when your page needs its.  Depending on your videos' compression, this might be a good idea because getting accurate pixel data for every frame could be difficult because of keyframes.

Comment: keyframes are exactly why I cannot use a flash app to just load the movie and grab frames in flash directly. QT doesn't require keyframes you can just tell it to move to an exact frame. unfortunately cannot pre-process since the amount of movies on the server is ludicrous. not youtube ludicrous but close.

Answer (score 0):

This example on Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Manipulating_video_using_canvas
uses the `getImageData()` function on the context object to do a chromakey replacement in a video.